# How can I filter content with conditional taxonomy terms?

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I have created a vocab (called like apple) that contains;
iOS: iPhone, iPad, iPod
Mac OSX: Mac pro, Macbook air, iMac...

Now I need/want to create a page/view; when my customer select 'iOS' from first drop-down, they can select iPhone, iPad etc. from second drop-down. And my page will be loaded with chosen values.

İt will like a multi-conditional boxes.

How can I do that, could you help me please?

Regards.

Comment: Did you Create a drupal view of taxonomy type

Comment: Hello, yes, I've created, But we can not use multiple drop-down menu with views taxonomy type.. You can read Maarten's answer below. Thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use https://www.drupal.org/project/shs in combination with views.

From the project page:

Views (exposed filter)

- add a new filter using the field set-up as "Simple hierarchical select" or
  use "Content: Has taxonomy terms (with depth; Simple hierarchical select)"
  as a new filter
- use "Simple hierarchical select" as selection type
- select "Expose this filter to visitors, to allow them to change it"
- enjoy ;)